# Django URL Regex Capture Int

Tags: django

My aim is to pass 2 arguments from my namespace into my other views.

```
  <li><a href ="{% url world:p p.id 1 %}">{{p.description}}
```

I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense . I'm trying my best to find the right words to describe my problem.

The argument , I'm trying to pass into the delpic function inside views.py are a picture id and an integer but inorder for it work , it must pass the regex and then it will be sent to my views.py.

```
def delpic(request,picture_id,digit):

     digit = digit
     If digit == "1":
               #Something
     If digit == "2":
               # Something
     return render(request,'boardeditor.html',{'board':BoardNameForm(request.user),})
```

but when I try to pass both into my views . I get this error

```
  TypeError at /delpic/3/1/

  delpic() takes exactly 3 non-keyword arguments (2 given)
```

I think it's my regex that casuing the problem

```
    url(
        r'^delpic/(?P<picture_id>\d+)/(\d{1})/$',
        'pet.views.delpic',
        name= 'delpic',
    ),
```

My Main URL CONF

```
url(
    r'^',
    include('pet.urls',
        namespace = 'world')
),
```

Comment: You haven't registered your url with a namespace: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls

Comment: just a side note, your function delpic returns something before you process your digit variable, dont think thats your intention...

Comment: Why dont you just copy your `picture_id` regexp and add it on renaming it?

Comment: `r'^delpic/(?P<picture_id>\d+)/(?P<digit>\d+)/$'` - like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the regexp wrongly.

The view is expecting a named regexp and you're not naming it.
The view doesn't understand what's happening.

The correct regexp for your view is this:

```
r'^delpic/(?P<picture_id>\d+)/(?P<digit>\d+)/$'
```